# Unable to select from dropdown in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Relatively new to python and selenium. Trying to run the below code in python using selenium library. The drop down does not get activated on using the css selector. Also im not sure if im using the right syntax for selecting the date.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.!!

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

s=Service("C:\\python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window()
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,20)
driver.get('http://www.amfiindia.com/research-information/other-data/mf-scheme-performance-details')
time.sleep(2)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#form-fund-details > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > button > span.bs-caret > span"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@class='end-type']/a[.='Open-ended']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"##form-fund-details > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > button > span.bs-caret > span"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@class='primary-category']/a[.='Debt']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#form-fund-details > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > button > span.bs-caret > span"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@class='category']/a[.='Medium Duration']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#form-fund-details > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.col-sm-3.pdl0 > div > div > button > span.bs-caret > span"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@class='amc']/a[.='All']"))).click()

datefield = driver.find_element_by_id('nav-date')
datefield.click()
datefield.send_keys("09-Mar-2022")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.btn btn-primary amfi-btn'))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#download-report-excel > img"))).click()

driver.quit()
```

Comment: What are the manual steps to repro the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just skip using Selenium here. The only issue is that it is checked for CAPTCHA with cloudflare. However, there is a nifty package to handle that:

first do `pip install cloudscraper` in your environment.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import cloudscraper

nav_date = '09-Mar-2022'
url = 'https://www.valueresearchonline.com/amfi/fund-performance-data/'
payload = {
    'end-type': '1',
    'primary-category': 'SDT',
    'category': 'SDT_MD',
    'amc': 'ALL',
    'nav-date': nav_date}

scraper = cloudscraper.CloudScraper()
res = scraper.get(url, params=payload).text

df = pd.read_html(res)[0]
df.to_csv(f'fund-performance-{nav_date}.csv')
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
                                    Scheme                      Benchmark       Riskometer           Latest NAV (₹)  Previous NAV (₹)          1-Year Return (%)3-Year Return (%)5-Year Return (%)10-Year Return (%)Returns Since Launch (%)                                     Daily AUM (Cr.)
                                    Scheme                      Benchmark           Scheme Benchmark                          Regular   Direct                                                                                       Regular Direct Benchmark Unnamed: 9_level_1 Daily AUM (Cr.)
0   Aditya Birla Sun Life Medium Term Fund  CRISIL Medium Term Debt Index        Very High  Moderate                          26.2581  27.8779                                                                                          9.20   9.84      6.38                NaN         1543.26
1                 Axis Strategic Bond Fund    NIFTY Medium Duration Index  Moderately High  Moderate                          22.1686  23.8259                                                                                          5.56   6.31      6.19                NaN         1836.37
2             BNP Paribas Medium Term Fund  CRISIL Medium Term Debt Index         Moderate  Moderate                          15.3021  16.2018                                                                                          3.81   4.39      6.38                NaN           19.34
3                            DSP Bond Fund  CRISIL Medium Term Debt Index         Moderate  Moderate                          65.8516  69.1150                                                                                          4.41   4.80      6.38                NaN          356.60
4               HDFC Medium Term Debt Fund    NIFTY Medium Duration Index  Moderately High  Moderate                          45.4989  48.2688                                                                                          5.73   6.53      6.19                NaN         4094.24
5   ICICI Prudential Medium Term Bond Fund  CRISIL Medium Term Debt Index  Moderately High  Moderate                          35.5755  38.2344                                                                                          5.61   6.35      6.38                NaN         6886.97
6          IDFC Bond Fund Medium Term Plan    NIFTY Medium Duration Index         Moderate  Moderate                          37.8636  40.3042                                                                                          4.57   5.30      6.19                NaN         2564.22
7                   Kotak Medium Term Fund    NIFTY Medium Duration Index         Moderate  Moderate                          18.2767  19.6585                                                                                          6.03   7.12      6.19                NaN         2975.84
8            L&T Resurgent India Bond Fund    NIFTY Medium Duration Index         Moderate  Moderate                          16.4484  17.5125                                                                                          4.81   5.76      6.19                NaN         1037.95
9         Nippon India Strategic Debt Fund  CRISIL Medium Term Debt Index             High  Moderate                          12.5607  13.3599                                                                                         18.24  18.89      6.38                NaN          230.34
10         SBI Magnum Medium Duration Fund    NIFTY Medium Duration Index  Moderately High  Moderate                          40.9884  43.5373                                                                                          4.87   5.44      6.19                NaN        10426.94
11          Sundaram Medium Term Bond Fund    NIFTY Medium Duration Index         Moderate  Moderate                          58.8925  63.8394                                                                                          2.87   3.97      6.19                NaN           59.83
12                   Tata Medium Term Fund  CRISIL Medium Term Debt Index         Moderate  Moderate                          29.5529  32.3416                                                                                          5.57   6.55      6.38                NaN           83.34
13              Union Medium Duration Fund  CRISIL Medium Term Debt Index         Moderate  Moderate                          10.6048  10.6718                                                                                          4.82   5.21      6.38                NaN          219.25
14                    UTI Medium Term Fund  CRISIL Medium Term Debt Index         Moderate  Moderate                          14.9461  15.6951                                                                                          7.24   8.01      6.38                NaN           61.28
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Love this approach. However, the output which is generated is the table visible on the html page which does not have the 3-5-10 yr Returns%. Ideally what is required is to download the excel which is generated after hitting the go button which contains all these details

Comment: Ah ok. So you need the % yr returns as well?

Comment: @chitown88..yes..so clicking on various dropdowns then clicking on Go button and then downloading the excel

Comment: Ok. I'll take a look at this later.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what the problem is. I am assuming from your description that you are finding an issue choosing the date from the date picker? If so, the date picker is in an Iframe. We need to switch to it first. Also we need to clear the content of the input field before we send the new data. Quick and dirty code below. Hope this helps. This is in Java. From the syntax, you can easily substitue for eq Python.

```
driver.get("https://www.amfiindia.com/research-information/other-data/mf-scheme-performance-details");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@src=' https://www.valueresearchonline.com/amfi/fund-performance']")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#nav-date")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#nav-date")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#nav-date")).sendKeys("07-Mar-2022");
```